# SwitchPreference stop working if setOnPreferenceChangeListener is implemented in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment, onpreferenceclicklistener

I've implemented SwitchPreference in PreferenceFragment and it works like a champ. But when I implement setOnPreferenceChangeListener on it its state does not change on the click event. Here is my implementation. Please have a look.

```
track_location = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("location_tracking");
track_location.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

if I remove the listener line, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return true inside onPreferenceChange

Comment: Thanks buddy, Sometimes small stupid things waste the whole day. though i did the same thing so many times